# Add custom style to the footer of Table

Tags: css, sapui5

I have two component Text https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Text/samples

Two texts are in two different position:

- Text1 is the text in a [form](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleForm354/preview)   (label: **text**)
- Text2 is in the [footer area of a table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Column/aggregations)

Ok. In each text I set a the class property:

```
<Text text="hello world" class="functionTag"/>
```

and in my `css/style.css` file I add:

```
.functionTag {
    color: red;
}
```

**In Text1 (form) the color changes to red, in Text2 the color remains black.** Why? *Footer has own style that I can't overwrite?* How can I do it whithout change the footer style for each table?

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: There is no element with the class `functionTag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one,

```
.functionTag {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to diagnose this problem without code. In the mean time though, you can put `!important` on the end of your tag though to make it work. Like the following `color: red !important`.

That is a way that you COULD fix it, let me remind you though that to use `!important` is a bad practice.

Again, more code will help us solve your problem :)